# Multiple joins on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to achieve a query which seems simple but I can't make it work correctly. Here's my database tables structures:

```
members
    -> id
    -> last_name
    -> first_name
```

```
activities
    -> id
```

```
registrations
    -> id
    -> member_id
```

```
tandems
    -> id
    -> activitie_id
    -> registration_member_one
    -> registration_member_two
```

Here's what i want to achieve:

Mutliple members can register to an activity. Then, i group the registrations by tandems. I want a view with all the tandems listed and there's my problem. When I try a query, it gives me multiple rows, duplicated many times.

Below, an example of the table I want to have:

```
tandems.id | activities.id | registration_member_one.members.last_name | registration_member_two.members.last_name
1          | 3             | John Doe                                  | Jane Doe
```

Here's the query I'm working on:

```
SELECT
tandems.*,
memberOne.id, memberOne.last_name, memberOne.first_name,
memberTwo.id, memberTwo.last_name, memberTwo.first_name,
memberOne_registration.member_id as memberOne,
memberTwo_registration.member_id as memberTwo

FROM tandems

JOIN registrations as memberOne_registration
ON memberOne_registration.member_id = tandems.registration_member_one
JOIN members as memberOne ON memberOne.id = memberOne_registration.member_id

JOIN registrations as memberTwo_registration
ON memberTwo_registration.member_id = tandems.registration_member_two
JOIN members as memberTwo ON memberTwo.id = memberTwo_registration.member_id

WHERE activitie_id = 3;
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your query seems to be missing a `FROM` clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by joining wrong column (`member_id`) of `registrations` table with `tandems` table, instead column `registrations.id` should be used.

```
SELECT
tandems.*,
memberOne.id, memberOne.last_name, memberOne.first_name,
memberTwo.id, memberTwo.last_name, memberTwo.first_name,
memberOne_registration.id as memberOne,
memberTwo_registration.id as memberTwo

FROM tandems
JOIN registrations as memberOne_registration ON memberOne_registration.id = tandems.registration_member_one
JOIN members as memberOne ON memberOne.id = memberOne_registration.member_id
JOIN registrations as memberTwo_registration ON memberTwo_registration.id = tandems.registration_member_two
JOIN members as memberTwo ON memberTwo.id = memberTwo_registration.member_id

WHERE activitie_id = 3;
```

Comment: @BeeInteractive, pls check if it helps

Comment: To Grace & Nick, it was a typo, sorry for that!

Comment: To Grace: Nope, still the same result. The rows are duplicated..

Comment: @BeeInteractive, a correction is made again, pls check.

Answer (score 1):

Although other query is virtually the same, I hate working with unnecessarily long alias names so worked with  "r1" and "r2" for the two instances of the registration table, and "m1" and "m2" for the members joining context.

```
SELECT
        t.id,
        t.activitie_id,
        m1.last_name LastName1,
        m1.first_name FirstName1,
        m2.last_name LastName2,
        m2.first_name FirstName2
    FROM 
        tandems t
            LEFT join registrations r1
                ON t.registration_member_one = r1.id
                LEFT JOIN members m1
                    ON r1.member_id = m1.id
            LEFT join registrations r2
                ON t.registration_member_two = m2.id
                LEFT JOIN members m2
                    ON r2.member_id = m2.id
    WHERE 
        t.activitie_id = 3;
```

To help you on this and in the future... Although mentally done, I try to mentally draw out how do I get the pieces together from the first table downstream.  This can be seen too by the visual indentation almost like a tree view extension from T to R1 to M1, then R2 to M2 is a different branch.  I also prefer to list the left table/alias.column = right table/alias.column in the join condition.  How does T get to R1, then how does R1 get to M1.

In this, I used LEFT JOIN to each respective registration and member -- just-in-case only one person registered and a second may be pending. Not sure how your registration is actually structured.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Much appreciated!